How do I convert ethers js to wagmi?
Where I will have 2 signers (of one account, with different providers)
I have seen the reference link: https://wagmi.sh/core/guides/ethers
But still struggling
Here is the code that I'm trying to put the signers in:
export const relayUSDC = async (
  txhash: string,
  chain: Chain,
  signer: ethers.Signer
) => {
  // Step 1: Observe for the MessageSent event
  const srcContract = new ethers.Contract(
    MESSAGE_TRANSMITTER[chain],
    ["event MessageSent(bytes message)"],
    signer
  );

  const messageSentReceipt = await signer?.provider?.getTransactionReceipt(
    txhash
  );
  if (!messageSentReceipt) return;

  const log = getMessageSentEvent(srcContract, messageSentReceipt);

  if (log) {
    const message = log.args.message;
    // Step 2: Call the Attestation API to get the signature
    console.log("Receive MessageSent event: ", message);
    const messageHash = ethers.solidityPackedKeccak256(["bytes"], [message]);

    console.log("Getting signature from attestation API...");
    let signature = await fetchAttestation(messageHash);

    if (signature) {
      console.log("Received signature:", signature);
      const destChain =
        chain === Chain.AVALANCHE ? Chain.ETHEREUM : Chain.AVALANCHE;

      const destProvider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(RPC[destChain]);

      const destContract = new ethers.Contract(
        MESSAGE_TRANSMITTER[destChain],
        [
          "function receiveMessage(bytes memory _message, bytes calldata _attestation)",
        ],
        new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, destProvider) // suppose to be signer 2
      );

      // Step 3: Send a mint transaction
      try {
        console.log("Sending tx to mint USDC on", destChain, "...");
        const receipt = await destContract
          .receiveMessage(message, signature)
          .then((tx: any) => tx.wait());
        console.log("Minted USDC", receipt.hash);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("Failed to mint USDC", e);
      }
    }
  }
};

How can I execute the mint function (it worked normally if I initiate a new Wallet with the private key, connect it to the destination provider.)
But I don't want to have the private key here since I am building an Dapp
